# Definite integral $\int^\pi_{\pi/2}{\sqrt{1+\cos{2t}}.dt}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am having a problem with the sign of the answer.
$$\int^\pi_{\pi/2}{\sqrt{1+\cos{2t}}.dt}=\int^\pi_{\pi/2}{\sqrt{1+2\cos^2t-1}.dt}=\int^\pi_{\pi/2}{\sqrt{2\cos^2t}.dt}$$
$$\int^\pi_{\pi/2}{\sqrt2\cos{t}.dt}=\sqrt2\int^\pi_{\pi/2}{\cos{t}.dt}=\sqrt2.[\sin{t}]^{\pi}_{\pi/2}$$
$$\sqrt2.(\sin{\pi}-\sin{\pi/2})=\sqrt2.(0-1)=-\sqrt2$$
This is a problem from the book Thomas' Calculus (11th Edition) Q65, Exercises 8.1 and the answer is given as $\sqrt2$ not $-\sqrt2$. I put it in an [Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) and there also it is giving $\sqrt2$.
So, what mistake am I doing to get the extra minus sign?

Comment: Yet another indicator that something is off: the integrand is nonnegative, so the integral should be nonnegative. You fell into the trap assuming $\sqrt{y^2} = y$ when $\sqrt{y^2} = |y|$ is more correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When $t\in\left[\frac\pi2,\pi\right]$, $\cos t\leqslant0$, and therefore$$\sqrt{2\cos^2(t)}=\sqrt2|\cos(t)|=\color{red}-\sqrt2\cos(t).$$